# Is the average speed the distance divided by the expected average time?

Tags: probability, average

I have $N$ samples for the time a (same) person runs a distance $d$, this was measured by hand (i.e. the time has an error). And the person does not perform equally on each measurement.

What would be the conceptual difference of $\bar{v}$ and $\hat{v}$:

$$\bar{v} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{d}{t_i}$$

versus doing:

$$ \bar{t} =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {t_i} \rightarrow \hat{v} = \frac{d}{\bar{t}}$$

I was asked for the average speed of the person to run a distance $d$, and for that they asked me for $N$ samples. However it is not clear to me what should be the metric I am supposed to use. I guess the first one is the expected value of the velocity of the person, and the later the average velocity of the $N$ experiments. I am really confused on which one I am supposed to use.

Comment: Note: by Jensen's inequality, $\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{t_i} \ge \frac{1}{\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N t_i}$ (so $\bar{v}\ge \hat{v}$). I think it would be better to use the average of the average speeds (i.e. $\bar{v}$) instead of $\hat{v}$ to estimate the person's average speed.

Comment: I'm not sure why this needs to be complicated. The person has run a total distance $Nd$ in total time $\sum t_i$, so the average speed is $Nd/\sum t_i = \hat v$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's plug in some numbers.  Let $d=10$ meters.  If you have two samples, one of $1$ sec and one of $2$ sec, the runner did $10$ m/s once and $5$ m/s once.  If you average the speeds you get $7.5$ m/s.  If you average the times and get $1.5$ sec, the speed will be $6\frac 23$ m/s.  Which do you want?  If the times are close it won't matter.

Comment: Which one would you use ? It is still not clear which one I should use.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to have the average represent.  Averaging the times will give you the total distance divided by the total time, which would normally be called the average speed.